# PyTorch method for returning element with highest count in a 1D tensor?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

Is there a built-in PyTorch method that takes a 1D tensor, and returns the element in the tensor with the highest count?

For example, if we input `torch.tensor([2,2,2,3,4,5])`, the method should return `2` as it occurs the most. In case of a tie in frequency, the element with the lower value should be returned; inputting `torch.tensor([1,1,2,2,4,5])` should return `1`.

Just to be clear, I only wish to know if there's an existing built-in PyTorch method that does exactly this. If there's no such method, please refrain from posting the solution, as I'd like to try solving it on my own.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes `torch.mode()` is builtin function(read [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mode.html)) which handles both of your conditions.

`torch.mode(alpha,0) #alpha being the name of tensor`

Comment: not posting the complete solution as per your request ;)